# IF/THEN drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

After an extensive search, all I seem to find are cascading drop down list topics.  My situation is:

If M173=true then allow drop down list in cell K72, otherwise blank.

For reference, M173 is true or false dependent on whether a check box is checked or not elsewhere on the sheet.

I've tried various if statements and vlookups inside cell K72 and even indirect after opening up the data validation tab.

Is this possible without VBA?

Comment: Can you change True to yes for example, in that case it is possible without VBA

Comment: I don't see an option to change the value of the checked box to yes or no.  When I right click on the box>format control>control tab, my value options are unchecked, checked, mixed.  Then the cell link.  I guess I could tell another cell if =if(m173=true,"yes","no") but please explain how this would help the total process.

Comment: you can define name your drop down list `yes` and use indirect(cell reference(yes)) in the list of the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Like you said you can use another cell M1 for example :
`=If(M173=True,"Fine","No")`
I used Fine just in case you need Yes in another place.
Select the options of your Dropdown List and define Name `Fine`
In K72 create `Data Validation`, choose `List`
In Source write:
`=Indirect(M1)`
In that case when M1 is different from `Fine` the dropdown is empty, when you have Fine in M1 K72 will show the values that you want to choose from the list

**Update for Drop Down List become blank**
Define name a blank cell `No` make it in a special place so you don't use it for any value (near the Fine list or yes list)
Keep the data validation Source like before =Indirect(M1)
If M1 = "No" the List will become blank (you have to choose the blank to clear the cell if it has any value)
If M1="Yes" or "Fine" whatever you choose the List will have the options you need
Just use normal word for Define Name do not use `TRUE`, `False`...

To Clear it automatically you will need VBA

Comment: Yass, thank you for getting me this far.  It's definitely in the right direction.  I'm trying to add one more component though.  After your above suggestion, if M1=no, how do I make the drop down list appear blank? I have been trying the following formula inside the data validation window in the "source" section: =IF(INDIRECT(M1)="no","",INDIRECT(M1))

Comment: You want the drop down list to be blank or the cell of the dropdown validation automatically become blank?

Comment: I will update for drop down list appear blank (not automatically the cell become blank)

Comment: just the cell of the drop down validation (2nd option). in other words, the drop down list to appear only when M1=fine, otherwise blank.  Right now, when M1=no, K72 still shows a value.  You can't do anything, can't drop down the list, but there's a value in K72.

Comment: @Edward,, If you want the Drop Down blank when Cell `M173` is `False` then do this. Select any blank cell & Name it `NO`. Then whenever `M173` will be `False` Excel will replace DD value with Blank.

Comment: @Edward,, or  U can use this VBA ,,                                                 `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Err1:
    
    If Target = Range("M173") Then
    If Range("M173").Value = False Then
     
    Application.SendKeys ("%{UP}")

    End If
    End If
    
Err1:
    Exit Sub
    
End Sub`